# pyautogui is not working in ubuntu 18.04 . hotkeys not working outside the editor while it works inside the editor

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04, pyautogui

hello everyone i am using ubuntu 18 and python 3.6 but here is a bit of problem in pyautogui
it's writing and mouse functions are doing great but hotkeys got some problem

hotkeys are doing there jon inside the editor in my case it's pycharm but not outside the editor any kind of code for example:-
'ctrl' + 'alt' + 's' opens the settings in pycharm so the code

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "alt", "s")
```

works perfeclty

but code like

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.hotkey("alt", "tab")
```

everyone knows what it does but it doesn't work

i've tried this also

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.keyDown("alt")
pyautogui.press("tab")
pyautogui.keyUp("alt")
```

but same thing nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem

Here's what worked for me :

```
pyautogui.keyDown('alt')
pyautogui.keyDown('tab')
pyautogui.keyUp('tab')
pyautogui.keyUp('alt')
```

Comment: this does seems to work so do you think the  problem is with press command?